# Can't run interface and virtual interface at the same time

Tags: networking, wireless, raspberrypi, hostapd, adhoc

So I am trying to create an ad-hoc network between a couple of devices.
I also need to run hostapd in order to capture probe request packets.

I have a wireless adapter (TL-WN722N) that is capable of both of these modes.

When I set up `hostapd`, a virtual interface is created (`mon.wlan0`) and `wlan0` is put into master mode.

Now I am trying to create another virtual interface (`adhoc.wlan0`) using the command:

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 interface add adhoc.wlan0 type ibss
```

I am setting the ssid, channel, ip, netmask and broadcast for this interface.

My issue is that I can only have either `wlan0` or `adhoc.wlan0` up at any one time. If i try to have both interfaces up (using `sudo ifconfig <interface> up`) I get the error:

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Name not unique on network
```

Does anybody know if it is possible to have both the interface and virtual interface running at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't exactly what I was asking but I found a way solve my problem.

I removed `hostapd` and used the wlan0 interface for my ad-hoc network.

I created a virtual interface for monitoring traffic using:

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 interface add mon.wlan0 type
sudo ifconfig mon.wlan0 up
```

These 2 interfaces seem to work properly together. 
hope this helps somebody else.